# Cribbage score for hand of 6,7,7,8, plus a 6 cut card

Tags: cribbage

What is the total count for 6, 7 7 8 with a 6 cut card

Answer (score 3):

I count that as 20.

Two for each of the 15s (7+8) = 4.

Double-double run of three (3x4) = 12.

Two pairs = 4.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no Jack involved (his knob/his heels) which card is the cut doesn't matter. Suit also doesn't matter here because a flush needs 4 cards to be scored, with the 2 pairs there's at most 3 cards of one suit, just short of any possibility of flush scoring.

- You have 15 two ways there 7a + 8 ad 7b+8, for 2 points each (4 points)
- There are 4 ways of making a run of 3 there 6a,7a,8; 6a,7b,8; 6b,7a,8; 6b,7b,8 giving 3 points each (12 points)
- there are 2 pairs in the hand, 6s and 7s, for 2 points each (4 points)

This gives a score of 20 total for the hand.